# Pause and resume a foreach loop in PHP

Tags: foreach

It is possible to pause a foreach loop, inser some code, and then resume it?

Let me explain: I have an array with 9 elements and some data. I would like to loop the array grouping the elements by three and I would like to do this without creating three different foreach.

Like so:

```
<div class="first">
<ul>
[start foreach]
<li>Element 1</li>
<p>Element 1 data</li>
<li>Element 2</li>
<p>Element 2 data</li>
<li>Element 3</li>
<p>Element 3 data</li>
[pause foreach]
</ul>
</div>


<div class="second">
<ul>
[start foreach]
<li>Element 4</li>
<p>Element 4 data</li>
<li>Element 5</li>
<p>Element 5 data</li>
<li>Element 6</li>
<p>Element 6 data</li>
[pause foreach]
</ul>
</div>


<div class="third">
<ul>
[start foreach]
<li>Element 7</li>
<p>Element 7 data</p>
<li>Element 8</li>
<p>Element 8 data</p>
<li>Element 9</li>
<p>Element 9 data</p>
[pause foreach]
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using php loop statements around html is possible, it is sort of buried in the php.net manual, here is the exact page, the first example should be just about what you need.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

here is an example from a page I'm working on, it's part of the nav bar.

```
<ul class="menu_dropdown">
    <?php $categories = Category::find_all();
    foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
        <li class="submenu"><a href="products.php?category=<?php echo $category->id?>"><?php echo $category->name."?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach?>
</ul>
```

If you want to format it into the three different divs (columns?) it might be easier to take the query array and use a while or if statement to go through the different keys or values, because a foreach is going to do them all at once, unless you have 3 separate queries.

Comment: I would like to print three elements from an array, insert a single line of code, print other three elements from the same array, print a single line of code, print others three elements.

Comment: but is it static content or brought in from a database?

Comment: The array came from a database query. I would like to use just one query to retrieve the content, but I would like to format the array in three different ways.